# WhatsApp doesn't show image in link sharing?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, whatsapp, share-open-graph

Since this year (I think), all my sites with OpenGraph tags does not show image when an section or article is sent on whatsapp.

E.g: [My shopping website](https://shiftdigital.com.ar/productos/2229/lg+monitor+tecnico+24%22+24bk550yb+fhd+360%C2%BA+75hz+hdmi+dport+dvi+v)

Its contains these tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="LG Monitor Tecnico 24&quot; 24BK550Y-B FHD 360º 75Hz HDMI DPort DVI V">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://shiftdigital.com.ar/images/LG Monitor LED 24 24BK550Y-B 1.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://shiftdigital.com.ar/productos/2229/lg+monitor+tecnico+24%22+24bk550yb+fhd+360%c2%ba+75hz+hdmi+dport+dvi+v">
```

Using [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) I don't see any error and the image is visible.

I read many answer here and in other forums about image size but even using image urls that works in other pages, it 'til not working in mine.

Comment: Update: I can see WhatsApp android and windows users have this bug. Even when I refresh the page using Facebook Debugger its still old data (e.g: in the title, i use PRODUCT_NAME | STORE_NAME, and its send it as PRODUCT_NAME - STORE_NAME as I've used many month ago)

Comment: For some reason, your server is providing much of your page information as Unicode hex character codes (e.g. `<meta property="og&#x3A;type" content="article"`> rather than `<meta property="og:type" content="article">`). I don’t know if WhatsApp or Facebook will work with Unicode Hex character codes or not, but it does increase the size of your HTML file and often sites like Facebook and WhatsApp will request just the first part of your file (Facebook asks for the first megabyte), so your server might not be sending the image link for some requests. Try using regular text characters.

Comment: Hey @RichDeBourke, yes.. my framework added that. But I could verify the issue continues